# JSDoc for reused Function interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I'm connecting to multiple email tools and abstracting their APIs to one common `sendEmail` function with the same `params` and same `returns` for each service. That means that for every email service (Mailchimp, SendGrid...), I have to write a function which has an identical JSDoc describing the same `@params` and same `@returns`...

**Is there a valid JSDoc syntax to use `@typedef` or similar with a Function, where instead of declaring `@params` and `@returns` above each function, just describe the type?**

...Bonus points for not disabling ESLint's [`require-jsdoc`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-jsdoc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a way to define it. Use [@callback](https://jsdoc.app/tags-callback.html) which is the equivalent of `@typedef` for functions.

```js
/**
 * @callback sendEmail
 * @param {string} to
 * @param {string} body
 * @returns {boolean} to indicate success or failure
 */
```

You can then use `sendEmail` as a type:

```js
/**
 * @param {sendEmail} sender - function to send the email
 */
function createEmailService(sender) { ... }
```

The problem is there is not a good way to specify the type of a function because `@type` on a function is interpreted to be the return type of the function, not the entire function definition. So something like the following does not work.

```js
/**
 * @type {sendEmail}
 */
function mailchimpEmailSender(to, body) { ... }
```

You can get it to work with the following, but it is not a great solution. I am still looking for a better solution.

```js
/**
 * @type {sendEmail}
 */
let mailchimpEmailSender
mailchimpEmailSender = function(to, body) { ... }
```

**Update:**
I have figured out that if you wrap the function declaration in parens it seems to allow the `@type` to apply to the variable instead of the function declaration.

```js
/**
 * @type {sendEmail}
 */
const mailchimpEmailSender = (function(to, body) { ... })
```

This is the solution I like best thus far as it allows you to use the appropriate variable declaration keyword. The only downside is it requires you to remember to add in code that is not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It's near the end of 2022, and I believe this question needs an updated answer. I cannot confirm this solution for code editors oher than `VS Code`, but if they support `JSDoc@3.x`, they should be fine.

The solution uses `@callback` definitions, and TypeScript's `import(...)` statements (which, AFAIK, is only supported in `JSDoc@3`, thus, the version requirement).
Also, `JSDoc@3` apparently does not interpret `@type` declarations as the `return` type, instead, it applies the declaration to the entire statement that follows - thus a function will inherit the `@callback` declaration for itself.

### Solution

#### Define function signature

Create a `@callback` type specifying everything you need. In the example below, I am writing a `graphql-yoga` resolver function definition.

```js
/** @typedef {import("graphql").GraphQLResolveInfo} GraphQLResolveInfo */
/** @typedef {import("@graphql-yoga/node").YogaInitialContext} YogaInitialContext */

/**
 * @callback GQLResolver
 * @param {TObj} obj
 * @param {TArgs} args
 * @param {YogaInitialContext} context
 * @param {GraphQLResolveInfo} info
 * @template TObj
 * @template TArgs
 * @template TReturn
 * @returns {Promise<TReturn>}
 */
```

#### Reuse - in the same file

To reuse the type, simply apply it with a `@type` declaration:

```js
/** @type {GQLResolver< {}, { id: string }, boolean >} */
function someResolver(obj, args, context, info){}
// (obj: {}, args: { id: string }, context: YogaInitialContext, info: GraphQLResolveInfo) => Promise<boolean>

// You can also override the signature with additional `@param` and `@return` declarations
/**
 * @type {GQLResolver< {}, { id: string }, boolean >}
 * @param {{ otherId: number }} args
 * @param {{ something: string }} info
 * @return {Promise<{ success: boolean, errors: Array<string>}>}
 */
function someOtherResolver(obj, args, context, info) {}
// someOtherResolver = (
//    obj: {},
//    args: { otherId: number },
//    context: YogaInitialContext,
//    info: { something: string }
// ) => Promise<{ success: boolean, errors: Array<string> }>
```

#### Reuse types from an external files **without** `@template` parameters

Assuming that the `@callback GQLResolver` definition is in an external file `types.js`, make sure that the file exports at least an empty object - otherwise, it will not work. I don't know the exact reason, but it might be that JS/TS bails out when no symbols are exported.

```js
// ./src/types.js

/**
 * @callback GQLResolver
 * ...
 */

export {} // <-- at least this
```

Then, use a TS-like `import(...).TypeName` declaration:

```js
/** @typedef {import("types.js").GQLResolver} GQLResolver */

/** @type {GQLResolver} **/
function example(){}
```

**NOTE:**
If you have a JS file dedicated to typedefs like the above, please note that **you do not need to import it as JS source** in your project! The `typedef {import(...)}` works standalone, as long as the specified import exports any symobls.

#### Reuse from an external file with `@template` parameters

Importing types from external files, that make use of `@template` parameters, is possible, but it will not work as expected:

```js
/** @typedef { import("types.js").GQLResolver } GQLResolver */
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^
                                 <GQLResolver>     <any>
```

The `import` misses the `@template` declarations, and considers the type invalid - thus, assigns type `any`.
The workaround is to specify template parameters near the imported symbol name:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {import("types.js").GQLResolver<
 *   any,
 *   { id: string }
 *   boolean
 * }>} SomeSpecificGQLResolver
 */
// SomeSpecificGQLResolver = (obj: {}, args: { id: string }, context: YogaInitialContext, info: GraphQLResolveInfo) => Promise<boolean>

/** @type {SomeSpecificGQLResolver} */
function someResolver(obj, args, context, info){}
// someResolver = same as SomeSpecificGQLResolver
```